# How to remove link from application panel

Tags: 11.10, gnome-panel

In Ubuntu 11.10 with Gnome Classic shell I managed to add some links to the application panel (top panel with Applications, Places menu). But I don't know how to remove a link from the panel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> and right-click the short-cut link to be presented with a right-click menu.  You should be able to delete the link.

If you are using *fall-back mode* then this key combination is <kbd>Alt</kbd> and right-click

---

Linked Question:

1. [How to revert to GNOME Classic Desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58172/how-to-revert-to-gnome-classic)

Answer (score 0):

Well that button combination didnt work for me (im using fall-back)..

Solution: Right-click Applications button (top left corner) and then go to EDIT MENUs...

You should be able to take it from here, good luck!